# Solving for $a_j$ such that $\sum_j {a_j}^k = c_k$ for some given $c_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Basically the question is in the title.  I want to solve:

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty {a_j}^k = c_k,\;\;\; k=1,2,...$

for $a_j$, given some chosen $c_k$ (say, all variables are complex).  Are there some consistency conditions on $c_k$ such that this infinite set of equations for infinite unknowns has a solution?   And for such a valid $c_k$, how does one go about finding the solution?  I'm happy to do this in some kind of perturbative expansion in a small parameter, but even this seems difficult.

Comment: For starters, given a solution set $a_j$, you can arbitrarily set $a_j=0$ and then shift over the original solution (assuming the solution is absolutely convergent).